# Non-derogatory word for shill?

Tags: single-word-requests

There are situations where it would be helpful to have people buzzing around enthusiastically.  Examples would be an open house or a book signing.   What would you call people hired to attend such events?  Shill seems too harsh.

Comment: [*Extras*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extra_(acting))?

Comment: Shill, plant, astroturfing... all the words that come to mind are negative (probably because the act deliberately creates a false impression, and people don’t like to be made fools of).

Comment: A _claque_ used to be hired to applaud opera or theatrical performances — or to boo a rival soprano — but the word now is used to suggest a crowd of sycophants.

Comment: I think this is a good question.  If people who organize book signings have a name for this, it would be interesting to know.

Comment: If you're looking for a word to use when discussing, or hiring, "shills", I'd like to suggest a compound utilizing the current "buzz-word", *optics*: How about *"optic-guests"*. (It sounds like a nice thing.)

Comment: In duck hunting, they're called decoys.

Comment: I've heard the term "party pumpers" used for the paid dancers who try to get more people out on the dance floor, for example. Slang/joke term is "fluffers" but that's derogatory.

Comment: in show business; TV sitcoms filmed before an audience, stage shows, etc., "designated laughers" are sometimes employed as "plants" in the audience to spur the rest of the audience into larger expressions of genuine laughter. http://www.101bananas.com/library2/laugher2.html (paragraph 3 describes the author, a professional laugher, as "a kind of discreet claque")

Comment: There can't be a non-derogatory synonym for shill, because a shill by any other name is inherently derogatory.  So if you made up a new term, like the "rent-a-crowd" example below, it would be seen as derogatory as soon as you used it.

Comment: synthetic enthusiast?

Comment: I don't think it necessarily has to be derogatory - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seat_filler doesn't have negative connotations to most people, and is close to the same thing...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Claqueur.

https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/claqueur

Originally a person who was hired to applaud at a theatre performance. More generally, a person hired to create "enthusiastic buzz" at an event, as you put it.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Thank you for including a reference in your answer.

Comment: Collectively they are a *claque*.

Answer (score 13):

In psychological experiments, where you have actual subjects and people who the subject is meant to think are also subjects but are secretly working with the experimenters to influence them, I have seen the word **"confederate"** used.

https://www.alleydog.com/glossary/definition.php?term=Confederate

There are plenty of words that could generally be a positive version of "shill" (like "advocate"), but in the specific context you suggest I'm not sure there are that many, since it's a scenario of deliberate deception. Which is usually considered a bad thing.

Comment: It's possible some parts of American culture would find this word to be *more* negative than "shill", but other than that it's a good word.

Answer (score 11):

> **Rent-a-crowd** [plural rent-a-crowds]
>
> A group of people who are paid to attend an event to increase
>   attendance figures, rather than attending of their own
>   volition.
>
> The term is derived from a fictional company,
>   Rentacrowd Ltd., mentioned in the Peter Simple (Michael Wharton)
>   columns in the UK Daily Telegraph newspaper.

[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/rent-a-crowd)

...

> **rent-a-crowd** (also rent-a-mob) NOUN British informal
>
> A group of people regarded as regularly or instantly available for an
>   expedient purpose, especially a public demonstration.

[ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/rent-a-crowd)

While rent-a-mob is obviously pejorative, rent-a-crowd can come across as being more humorous.

Comment: I've never heard this in AmEng, but given the existence of "rent-a-cop" it would be readily understood, I think. Of course, rent-a-cop is a bit demeaning as well (eg they're not *real* cops, just *mall*  cops)...

Answer (score 11):

If you don't mind using two words, **"Paid Attendee"** is probably the clearest neutral way to convey the concept.

Comment: Consider "compensated" instead of paid.

Answer (score 6):

Promoter, one who is paid to promote an event or company.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Thanks for your answer. Please consider adding references to support the word you're suggesting.

Comment: Promoting an event and being paid to attend an event are two completely different things.

Answer (score 0):

The first word that springs to mind is 'compatriots'.

In science, any person who aids in the endeavor or experiment is called a compatriot.

Comment: You have a link to back up your claim about this? I've never heard this in terms of science (or any field for that matter). Compatriot is `Somebody from one's own country.` [wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/compatriot)

Comment: @JeffC it can also just mean "friend or colleague."

Comment: @stannius According to what source? Any word can be misused but I linked the definition above and it doesn't mean friend or colleague.

Comment: @JeffC https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/compatriot

Answer (score -2):

Most of the following related terms are similarly pejorative, except the last:
stooges
stool pigeons
flunkeys
flim-flams
dupes
snitches
chisellers
grifters
welchers
warm-ups (as in a warm-up act before the main act, often used before live comedy shows on TV to get the audience in the mood)

Alternatively, you could make up your own term based on a related concept, but the manipulative nature of the objective means it will be difficult to avoid the implication of deception. Some examples (gratis):
Fob-mob
foxers
stingers
wringers
diddlers

Comment: In some political activitiy (or commercial ?) you can hire a truckload of slogan shouters for a certain party in the morning and and the same gang shouts out orchestrated support for the opponent party in the evening. Only the flag on the truck needs to be changed. I dont know the right word. Maybe vshout4u?